# sh: react-scripts: command not found after running npm start

Tags: reactjs

I cloned a react application onto my system and ran following commands

```
npm install -g create-react-app
npm install --save react react-dom
```

After that i ran

```
npm start
```

But it threw the above mentioned error, It is working fine on my other system from which i pushed it on github. But it is not working on any other system after cloning whether windows or mac.

Comment: You created your app with `create-react-app app` and cded into it with `cd app` before running `npm start`?

Comment: it created it with create-react-app app

Comment: Try `npm install` before running `npm start`?

Comment: I was accidentally using `react-scripts-ts` instead of `react-scripts`.

Answer (score 679, accepted):

Check if `node_modules` directory exists.  After a fresh clone, there will very likely be no `node_modules` (since these are `.gitignore`'d).

### Solution

run `npm install` (or `yarn`) to ensure all deps are downloaded.

### Alternative Solution

If `node_modules` exists, remove it with `rm -rf node_modules` and then run `npm install` (or `yarn`).

Comment: This solution worked for me. But I also had to remove `package-lock.json`.

Comment: I also want to mention this happens **if the project is initialized using Yarn but then you attempt to run `npm install`**. This won't work: they're not compatible with each other. Running `npm install` on top of a Yarn-produced tree will corrupt it. I filed an issue [here](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/5240) but for now the solution is (if you use Yarn) to always use `yarn add` to add a package, and to delete `node_modules` and re-run `yarn` if you mess it up.

Comment: yes, it worked. But it seems like a common issue across the users. I would like to know what exactly causing the issue over here.

Comment: @ArunRamachandran cause of problem is in the first & second sentences: `After a fresh clone, there will very likely be no node_modules (since these are .gitignore'd).`

Comment: @DeBraid But I faced this problem after running 'npm install'. I cloned the repo, did npm install, later I had to add few more dependencies. The issue started after adding the additional dependencies. Is it overwriting something while installing the additional set of dependencies?

Comment: @ArunRamachandran the `package.json` file should not be overwritten when adding new deps with `npm install newDep`.  Perhaps your project is using `yarn`? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49575980/2700718

Comment: It didn't work for me, I even tried deleting package-lock.json file

Comment: `npm install --force` worked for me (after trying none of these answers work...)

Answer (score 79):

Tried all of the above and nothing worked so I used `npm i react-scripts` and it worked

Comment: This has fixed my issue. I had to run: yarn add react-scripts

Comment: didn't work for me

Answer (score 41):

I had similar issue. In my case it helped to have Yarn installed and first execute the command

`yarn`

and then execute the command

`yarn start`

That could work for you too if the project that you cloned have the yarn.lock file. Hope it helps!

Comment: Does anyone know WHY using `yarn` fixes an `npm` problem?

Comment: In my case, `yarn start` was not working as the dedicated port (8081) was reserved by previously running process. I had to kill it `kill -9 $(lsof -t -i:8081 -sTCP:LISTEN)
` and run `yarn start`

Answer (score 27):

In package.json, I changed

```json
"start": "react-scripts start"
```

to

```json
"start": "NODE_ENV=production node_modules/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js start"
```

I hope this solves the problem for some people. Although the other solutions above seem not to work for me.

Comment: react-scripts is not found in $PATH, any clue on how to add node scripts there?

Comment: Are you sure You've installed React either globally or to that project?

Comment: This response solved the issue for me, but right now, every single project need this to be able to start. How to fix this?

Answer (score 23):

you should not install react-scripts globally, for me this fixed the problem:

```
npm install --save react react-dom react-scripts
```

if this still dont work :

1. update to latest npm version : `npm install -g npm@latest`
2. delete `node_modules` directory
3. reinstall all dependencies : `npm install`

Comment: No luck for me, I even tried deleting package-lock.json

Comment: This three step thingie did it for me, nothing else worked!

Answer (score 17):

I had this problem for ages and I eventually found my solution by sheer chance.
Turns out, **you can't have spaces or wacky characters in any folder names**.

e.g.
`~/projects/tutorial/ReactJS/JavaScript Framework: ReactJS/app-name`
won't work because `JavaScript Framework: ReactJS` contains spaces.
In general, it's probably not great practice to be using spaces in folder/file names anyway but I hope this saves someone at least 4 hours of trial and error.

Also, **any non-alphanumeric characters should be avoided**.

Comment: wow, I tried everything said above but none worked, I didn't use space but had '&' in parent folder containing react app(not even in app's name).This is tricky thing, such small things can give so much issue

Comment: I've had the same problem, because a '&" in my path I lost the last 50 minutes trying to solve the problem :/

Comment: i had my app nested in a folder project:latest..
i think ':' was the culprit

Comment: I removed "spaces" and "/" from my path folder's names and it worked !!

Comment: Aaagh. I had a "/" in one of my folder names. This is apparently a bad idea. Changed that to a "-" and everything worked. Thanks

Answer (score 16):

https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app

```
npm install -g create-react-app

create-react-app my-app
cd my-app/
npm start
```

You install the create-react-app package globally.
After that you run it and create a project called `my-app`.
Enter your project folder and then run `npm start`. If that doesn't work try running `npm install` and then `npm start`. If that doesn't work as well, try updating your node version and/or npm.

Answer (score 11):

This error occurs when you Install package with `npm install` instead of `yarn install` or vice-versa.

Answer (score 7):

using `npm i --legacy-peer-deps` worked for me.

I do not know specifically which operation out of the following it performed:

- Installing the peer dependencies' latest stable version.
- Installing the peer dependencies' version which the core dependy you are installing uses.

But I think it performs the latter operation. Feel free to let me know if I'm wrong ^-^

Answer (score 6):

Run `npm i` before you start the react project

Answer (score 5):

```
npm install --save react react-dom react-scripts
```

Above command worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

If you are having this issue in a Docker container just make sure that node_modules are not added in the .dockerignore file.

I had the same issue sh1 : react scripts not found. For me this was the solution

Answer (score 4):

This boggles me time to time when I have a fresh start with create-react-app, please make sure your **NODE_ENV** variable is set to **development** not production, as devDependencies in your package.json will not be installed by npm install.

Answer (score 3):

Just ran into this problem after installing material-ui.

Solved it by simply running `npm install` again.

Answer (score 3):

Just doing an Yarn install solved the problem for me

Answer (score 3):

After spending too much time trying all the solutions above, I can say for sure:

If you ran into this issue, check your path. If the path contains any special character or spaces just rename it and make sure that the new path doesn't have any spaces or special character. Then run it again .

Comment: This seems rather vague. The `PATH` is not particularly sensitive to what characters your directory names contain, other than of course if a directory contains a literal `:` which is the `PATH` delimiter (but on a Mac, you can't really have colons in file names anyway IIRC). Naturally, you need to make sure that you have not misspelled the directories in your `PATH` (including but not limited to ensuring that your shell's strartup files don't contain DOS carriage returns, which could happen if you edit them on Windows; see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/)

Answer (score 2):

Deleting package-lock.json and node_modules then npm install worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

If none of the other answers work properly (after updating the npm etc). I would strongly recommend you to install the project on your desktop.

**create-react-app** *project_name*

Answer (score 2):

The solution that worked for me is below. Try creating React app with this command.

```
create-react-app react-app --scripts-version 1.1.5
```

Answer (score 2):

**this worked for me.**

**if you're using yarn:**

1. delete `yarn.lock`
2. run `yarn`
3. and then `yarn start`

**if you're using npm:**

1. delete `package-lock.json`
2. run `npm install`
3. and then `npm start`

Answer (score 2):

If anyone still have this problem after trying these solutions: check your project path as node has some issues working with spaced dir names. I changed all directories names that had spaces in their names and it worked perfectly.

solution idea taken from: https://npm.community/t/react-scripts-not-found/8574

i am using yarn BTW

Answer (score 2):

You shoundt use neither SPACES neither some Special Caracters in you path, like for example using "&". I my case I was using this path: "D:\P&D\mern" and because of this "&" I lost 50 minutes trying to solve the problem! :/

Living and Learning!

Answer (score 2):

I tried every answer but cleaning my npm cache worked..

**steps:**

1. Clean cache =====> npm cache clean force.
2. reinstall create-react-app =====> npm install create-react-app.
3. npm install.
4. npm start !!!

Comment: only reinstalling worked for me, didn't need to clean cache

Answer (score 2):

If you have tried everything and nothing solved it, try to rename the directories name. react will not start if the folder's name contains uppercase letters.

Answer (score 2):

This workaround works for me

```
// in your package.json replace 
"start": "react-scripts start"

// with:
"start": "node_modules/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js start"
```

Answer (score 2):

**delete node_modules**

1. run **npm install**
2. after that run **npm start**

**if above does't work**

1. delete **node_modules**
2. delete **package-lock.json**
3. run **npm install**
4. and then **npm start**

**if above solutions does not fixed your problem, try the following this worked for me:**

1. if you want to start on another port or PORT command not found error then do the following steps:

   1. open **package.json** file
   2. inside **script** replace the **start** command with below
      **"start": "set PORT=3006 && react-scripts start"**
   3. To change the port of your app, you can also create a new file name **.env** in the root directory of the project and write in it **PORT=3006** (then save the file). Now run your app using npm start.

Answer (score 1):

I just randomly experienced this "react-scripts: command not found" error after issuing a `react-scripts build` request, which was previously working just fine.

A simple reboot of my system corrected the issue.

Answer (score 1):

if anyone is willing to use npm only, then run this `npm i react-native-scripts --save`, then npm start or whatever the command you use

Answer (score 1):

### solution 1:

delete the package-lock.json file and then type -> npm install

### solution 2:

> /Users/piyushbajpai/.npm/_logs/2019-03-11T11_53_27_970Z-debug.log

like this is my debug path --> so this you will find in the console -> press on command and click on the link, you will find error line;
like this:

> **verbose stack Error: nest_form@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`**

### solution 3:

delete the node_module and npm i with fresh way.

### solution 4:

go to node_module and delete jses folder and delete it, then do npm i and again start with npm start

Answer (score 1):

I had issues with latest version of yarn `1.15.1-1`

I've fixed it by downgrading to lower version `sudo apt-get install yarn=1.12.3-1`

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this error after renaming the directory with the `@/` symbol on macOS to match the name of my NPM package namespace.

When the NPM command looked for installed packages in my local `node_modules`, it couldn't find it due to the way macOS was rewriting the directory path. After renaming the directory without `@/` I was up and running again.

Answer (score 1):

Just You have to restore packages to solve this issue,
So just run command :

npm install or yarn install

Answer (score 1):

For me it was deleting `package-lock.json` and `node_modules` and then run `npm install` again.

Answer (score 1):

**Replace**

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "../node_modules/.bin/react-scripts start",
    "build": "../node_modules/.bin/react-scripts build",
    "test": "../node_modules/.bin/react-scripts test",
   "eject": "../node_modules/.bin/react-scripts eject"
}
```

**with this**

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For my case I had a package that was out of date and could not be install via npm.
For my case the package was node-sass version 7.0.1 which is currently unavailable.
I changed the package to version 9.0.0 in the package.json file and this solved the problem:

```
npm i node-sass@9.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

If the above solutions don't work and you saw the below error:

```
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.

npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
```

try with `sudo npm install`

Answer (score 0):

just run these commands

```
npm install
npm start
```

or

```
yarn start
```

Hope this will work for you
thank you

Answer (score 0):

None of these solutions worked for me. I found that the problem was the directory I was creating the project in, I am not sure why but when I created the project outside of that directory it worked. My solution was changing the directory to a new one from "React/Ionic" to "ionic-react". It could be that not only the project itself should be lowercase, but its parent folder as well, or it could be that the "/" in the directory name be the issue. Hope this helped.

Comment: Directory names absolutely cannot contain slashes on any modern platform.

Answer (score 0):

fixed it with

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```

If you use npm to install and npm version is less than 7, then its npm most likey to behave in a smarter way. So, it will try to install react with its other depencies(peer deps)(higher versions if found), which will likely to break the library react. Attaching --legacy-peer-deps will tell npm "not to do something new", and install whats given in package.json...

Btw people seem to find yarn comfortable because this "not to install higher version if even found" is built in yarn automatically

reference: [A referenced question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66239691/what-does-npm-install-legacy-peer-deps-do-exactly-when-is-it-recommended-wh)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue until I ran this piece of code in my Mac terminal:

```
sudo npm install -g yarn
```

Apparently, I was missing **yarn** on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

1. delete package-lock.json file
2. delete node_modules folder
3. sudo npm i --force
4. Enter your laptop login password (if asked)
5. wait for node_modules to get installed
6. npm start

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue with a global update of all dependency.

`npm outdated | awk 'NR>1 {print $1"@"$4}' | xargs npm install`

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that i'd renamed the folder to 'repo/project' which in CLI read as 'repo:project'. I don't think it liked that.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above helped me..

For me there was something very strange.

The path of my project was something like this:
/Downloads/package_name/project_name

From some reason, in the Download folder there was some left package.json file

I figured this out when I tried to run the script directly from
project_name/node_modules/.bin/react-scripts build

The script failed and pointed this file as a problem

Once i deleted this orphaned package.json, it started to work.

I even then succeeded to reproduced this by creating empty package.json in the Downloads directory and the problem returned..

Answer (score 0):

In my case I moved the source code to the new folder, but "scripts" in package.json pointed to the previous location of node_modules

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your start script to use the appropriate command for your operating system. Here's how you can adjust it:

For Unix-based systems (Linux, macOS):
export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && react-scripts start

For Windows:
SET NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && react-scripts start

Answer (score -1):

Another reason I found for this issue:

The react runs the server at `http://localhost:3000`. If any server is already running at this port or this port is open in browser then command line throws `sh: react-scripts: command not found` error.

Comment: This is not the reason that they are getting the error above, in your case the error would be that something is already running on Port 3000. They have probably not installed any packages yet and hence react-scripts cannot be found.

Comment: @RahulKadukar I have the react-scripts package installed, but still it is throwing react-scripts cannot be found. I tried reinstalling the package, tried deleting the node_modules folder and then npm i again but still it didn't fix the issue. Then I fixed it by the procedure I mentioned above hence I commented. In your opinion, what could be other possible reason for the issue?