# react-scripts: command not found

Tags: reactjs

I am currently trying to use create-react-app which uses three different packages: react, react-scripts and react-dom. I have installed create-react-app and then when I change into the directory and hit `npm start` I get a `react-scripts: command not found`. I've ran into a lot of problems with this. I can see `react-scripts` is in my `node_modules` folder but I keep getting `command not found` when trying to run `npm start`. I tried to delete and re-install all of my `node_modules` but it didn't work. Anyone else having this issue?

```
 ✘ ✝  Node/toDoApp/my-test   master±  npm start

> my-test@0.1.0 start /Users/jzilch/Desktop/Web 
Projects/Node:Express/Node/toDoApp/my-test
> react-scripts start

sh: react-scripts: command not found
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! my-test@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the my-test@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely 
additional logging output above.
```

Comment: Create react app uses yarn. Did you try yarn start?

Comment: Tried this with Yarn too and got the following after first trying to add with Yarn Globally
     `✝  Node/toDoApp/my-test   master±  yarn start
    yarn run v1.3.2
    $ react-scripts start
    /bin/sh: react-scripts: command not found
    error Command failed with exit code 127.
    info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this 
    command.`

Comment: If you run npm install in the project directory. What happens?

Comment: Everything installs but I do get an error on fsevents
`
> fsevents@1.1.2 install /Users/jzilch/Desktop/Web Projects/Node:Express/Node/toDoApp/my-test/node_modules/fsevents
> node install

events.js:182
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
`

Comment: My advice honestly would be to update node and create react app and then run through the process again. Preferably using sudo or admin depending on your OS

Comment: Thanks. I tried to uninstall and re-install Node with Homebrew but still is not working. With yarn I do get more incite on what might be breaking. Yarn start return 
`/bin/sh: react-scripts: command not found`
Leading me to believe that its trying to find this fine in /bin/sh: instead of node_modules. Not sure on this one as system files are not my forte

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sh: react-scripts: command not found after running npm start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40546231/sh-react-scripts-command-not-found-after-running-npm-start)

Answer (score 93):

Firstly Delete `package-lock.json` file in your project folder.

And then install dependencies again by `npm install`. That should solve this issue.

Comment: While deleting use "rm -rf"

Comment: package.json is not a directory so -rf should not really be necessary here.

Comment: package-lock.json is the file they're suggesting you delete, not package.json -- @Jim assuming this was just a typo, but want to save people some time if possible.

Comment: Why suggesting package-lock.json should be deleted?

Answer (score 42):

Delete the `/node_modules` directory and the `package-lock.json` file using the `rm` command:

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm -rf package-lock.json
```

Install react-scripts using the following command:

```
npm install react-scripts
```

Install the dependencies using the following command:

```
npm install
```

Start the local server by running the following command:

```
npm run start
```

Comment: You are deleting `package.json` not `package-lock.json` with your command :)

Comment: In case the edit doesn't go through, the last note is questionable. If you have to resort to `sudo` for `npm` commands, there's likely something wrong with the node installation.

Answer (score 32):

This usually happens because of a bad npm packages installation (using npm and yarn at the same time?). It can be dispiriting, but if you try these steps, it should work.

**NPM solution:**

At the project's root folder, run:

```
> rm -rf node_modules
> rm -rf package-lock.json
> npm install
```

**YARN solution:**

At the project's root folder, run:

```
> rm -rf node_modules
> rm -rf yarn.lock
> yarn upgrade
> yarn
```

Next time you want to add a dependency using create-react-app, I recommend you to use 'yarn add' instead of 'npm install'.
(Source: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1155)

Answer (score 10):

I use this in a dockerizer enviroment.
I already install locally in node_modules using `package.json`.

so, I added this:

```
RUN npm install -g react-scripts
RUN npm install
```

That solved my confusing issue

Answer (score 9):

One option is to install the `react-scripts` package globally using the `-g` flag. This will make the command available to node, regardless of the working directory.

This command will install `react-scripts` globally:

```
npm install -g react-scripts
```

Answer (score 7):

As I was using `yarn`, I had to run `yarn add react-scripts`.

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem for ages and I eventually found my solution by sheer chance.
Turns out, **you can't have spaces in any folder names**.

e.g.
`~/projects/tutorial/ReactJS/JavaScript Framework: ReactJS/app-name`
won't work because `JavaScript Framework: ReactJS` contains spaces.
In general, it's probably not great practice to be using spaces in folder/file names anyway but I hope this saves someone at least 4 hours of trial and error.

I would recommend removing the `:` from your folder names too! (just to be safe)

Comment: My issue was caused by me using `npx create-react-app app-name` inside of a folder named "npm/node" or `npm:node`. Using the command in a different directory named `npm-node` worked.

Comment: In addition to this answer, an ampersand (&) can also cause this issue. This happened in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Delete your

- node_modules
- yarn.lock
- manifest_lock.json

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by changing folder name in my local system, from

```
new/landing
```

to

```
new_landing
```

However, the git branch name remains like "new/landing". This was the case with my MAC system.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I deleted the project and initialized another one with the `npm create-react-app <Folder Name>` script. Instead of `create-react-app <Folder Name>`.
It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

$yarn
$yarn run start

Running these commands two commands worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If anyone's having this issue with yarn, you can do

```
yarn global add react-scripts
```

and then delete your `package-lock.json` and `node_modules` folder.

Then, you can navigate to the main folder, and just do `yarn` and it will do a fresh install of your `package.json` dependencies.