# Why does i get following error on npm start

Tags: javascript, reactjs

h: react-scripts: command not found
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! client@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the client@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [react-scripts: command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47612580/react-scripts-command-not-found)

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting `package-lock.json` and then run
`npm install` before `npm start`.