# 'react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file - 2022

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I am facing this problem after I run this command " npm start " in visual studio 2022.

How I can fix this issue?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/48064931/15011621

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`npm install` first. The dependencies are not loaded