# How to resolve sh: react-scripts: command not found?

Tags: macos, reactjs, create-react-app, yarnpkg

I used create-react-app to generate an app.

```
create-react-app myapp
```

When I run yarn start or npm start I get this error:

> > react-scripts start
>
> sh: react-scripts: command not found npm ERR! file sh npm ERR! code
>   ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno ENOENT npm ERR! syscall spawn npm ERR!
>   myapp@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start` npm ERR! spawn ENOENT npm
>   ERR!  npm ERR! Failed at the myapp@0.1.0 start script. npm ERR! This
>   is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging
>   output above.

When I run npm ls react:

```
myapp@0.1.0 /Users/johnno/foosball 
└── react@16.2.0
```

react-scripts is present.

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.17",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "yarn": "^1.3.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

I tried the suggestions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40546231/sh-react-scripts-command-not-found-after-running-npm-start) but to no avail. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Can we see all the commands you ran?

Comment: see above updated the question

Comment: Which version of node are you using? Did you try `sudo npm start`?

Comment: node version 5.0.3

Comment: sudo npm start makes no difference

Comment: @bierhier Could you try the following 2 things?  
1. Run `npm ls react` and paste output here
2. Check if node_modules have react scripts. From root of your project, run `./node_modules/.bin/react-scripts start`

Comment: see above for result

Comment: ./node_modules/.bin/react-scripts start does not work since there is no react-scripts in the .bin even though I ran npm install again

Comment: Cool. now we know what the problem is. Your package manager is not installing all node modules correctly. I use Yarn so I'd urge you to use the same. Uninstall Yarn first. then install using directions here
https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install Now remove node modules using `rm -rf node_modules` and run yarn again. This should fix things

Comment: @bierhier, I made a few edits to your question as well. Please review

Comment: Npm start should work too right?

Comment: Why do I need yarn?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161354/discussion-between-sudo-bangbang-and-bier-hier).

Answer (score 9):

i solved this by deleting

> node_modules
>   yarn.lock
>   manifest_lock.json

and installed packages by

```
npm install
```

or

```
yarn
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, this worked for me as well. As a generalization, I expect that all "lock" files should be deleted. (And of course, run ```npm install``` to regenerate node_modules/.)

Comment: I was trying to fix this in a web based project, 'yarn' works for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Following steps worked for me

1. delete `node_modules` folder
2. delete `yarn.lock` if you are using `yarn` command or delete `package-lock.json` if you are using `npm` command
3. run `yarn install` (for yarn command) or `npm install` (for npm command)