# First app with create-react-app, npm start not working

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, npm-start

I am trying create my first react app and running into issues basically at step 1. I am trying npm start on the default create-react-app install and I am getting the follow error. I have included screenshots showing create-react-app ran successfully but that has not fixed anything. I have included screenshots of it successfully running create-react-app and of me running npm start with no luck. Thanks.

Here is the log file:

18 verbose npm  v6.4.1
19 error file sh
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno ENOENT
22 error syscall spawn
23 error robofriends@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
23 error spawn ENOENT
24 error Failed at the robofriends@0.1.0 start script.
24 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
25 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

I tried this solution and it did not work for me:

stackoverflow.com/a/42539669/5069226

[create-react-app running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrDen.png)

[npm start failing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFYEK.png)

Comment: see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/42539669/5069226

Comment: I tried that and it unfortunately did not fix my issue :(

Comment: Did you remove `package-lock.json` before doing `npm install`?

Comment: I did not..should I have?

Comment: Could you run `tail -n 1000 /Users/Neil/.npm/_logs/<that long filename from the error screenshot>.log` and add that to the post please. Please copy and paste from the console, because it is easier for us to work with.

Comment: tried again after removing package-lock too and no luck

Comment: I added it @stef

Comment: Do you have still space left in your file system?

Comment: @AlejandroVales I believe so but not sure...how can I check?

Comment: Basically open some file explorer and see how much space left you have in the disk you want to create the react app

Comment: ahh I see what you mean now and yes there is free space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this has to do with your workspace path.

I tried to replicate this on my machine with the path `/tmp/Users/Neil/Desktop/Complete Web Developer/Section 18_React:Redux/robofriends`, and i was able to reproduce your error.

```
╭─  /tmp/Users/Neil/Desktop/Complete Web Developer/Section 
18_React:Redux/robofriends 
╰ yarn start                                                                                                                                                                                                     K8S: tools    11:37:33
yarn run v1.7.0
$ react-scripts start
/bin/sh: react-scripts: command not found
error Command failed with exit code 127.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

But when i moved the `robofriends` directory up higher in the tree, it worked fine.

```
╭─  /tmp/Users/robofriends 
╰ yarn start                                                                                                                                                                                             K8S: tools  INT(-2) ↵  11:38:34
yarn run v1.7.0
Starting the development server...
```

I guessed it could be either the long path to node modules or the non-alphanum characters you have in your path, `:`,`_`. So i went back down to the `React:Redux` directory and renamed it to `...React_Redux` and tried `npm start` again in /tmp/Users/Neil/Desktop/Complete Web Developer/Section 18_React_Redux/robofriends`, and it worked just fine :)

So looks like `npm` doesn't like the `:` in the executable path.

Comment: I suspected it was something like that! Well done :-)

Comment: I am trying it as we speak

Comment: this was it!!! thank you sir :) I was literally on the first video of a react course and so bummed I couldn't even get this much working