# How can i run a demo React Native Code on Phone

Tags: react-native

Im totally new to React Native and just learned to setup the necessary environments and follow these steps;

1. Install Node.js
2. Download Expo client at mobile device
3. npm install -g create-react-native-app
4. cd to my desired directory
5. create-react-native-app some_app_name
6. cd to my app folder containing default app.js
7. npm start
8. basic / empty app will be loaded on my phone and code can be opened using editor of choice.

Now i've downloaded some demo simple apps from github and udemy (with full source code)

I tried to extract the files and cd to the folder and execute "npm start"
However, there is always this error

react-native-scripts: command not found
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! demo_app@0.1.0 start: `react-native-scripts start`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the demo_app@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

May i know what is missing? How do i get this right?

Answer (score 1):

The command to run a react-native app is **react-native run-android** for android devices and **react-native run-ios** for ios devices. Are you sure that you are running these commands to start the app?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this might be a duplicate of:

[sh: react-scripts: command not found after running npm start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40546231/sh-react-scripts-command-not-found-after-running-npm-start)