# Problems with npm errors

Tags: npm, webpack, node-modules, create-react-app

I have a problem with create-react-app. When I type npm start into my console it show's multiple errors. I installed the newest version of node and webpack, and also do everything from this [link](https://doreentseng.github.io/when-npm-start-shows-error-with-create-react-app/).

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! new-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the new-app@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Sakuy\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-10-02T20_14_18_618Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed `react-scripts` globally?.

It might be worth checking this [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40546231/sh-react-scripts-command-not-found-after-running-npm-start)

Comment: I just deleted node_modules globally and it work's now.