# create-react-app - react-scripts: command not found

Tags: reactjs, npm

i've just started out with react on codepen, and I really enjoy it! I decided to install it on my MacBook Air. I installed create-react-app using npm, and everything looked good. I then started a project, and everything went smoothly. When I ran `npm start`, I got an error:

```
sh: react-scripts: command not found
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! react-app@0.1.0 start: 'react-scripts start'
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the react-app@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I've come to the conclusion that npm can't find react-scripts. I have done almost everything I have come up with: I have updated npm; I have reinstalled the modules; I have started a new project, but I still get the same error. I've checked, react-scripts is in my node_modules file. The only thing I haven't done is install react-scripts globally, but the creator of create-react-app has said that that is a very bad idea. What should i do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sh: react-scripts: command not found after running npm start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40546231/sh-react-scripts-command-not-found-after-running-npm-start)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just solved the problem:

In `package.json`, I changed `"start": react-scripts start"`, to `"start": "NODE_ENV=production node_modules/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js start"`. This solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try running `npm install` before running `npm start`, if that doesn't work check out this article on the same issue - [sh: react-scripts: command not found after running npm start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40546231/sh-react-scripts-command-not-found-after-running-npm-start/42539669)

Comment: Have you tried all the steps in that post? Like rebooting your system and setting the NODE_ENV to development?

Answer (score 1):

Adding the entire path also worked for me: 
`"start": "node_modules/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js start"`

instead of just:
`"start": "react-scripts start"`.

I wish I knew why this behavior changed in my pc. 
Coincidence or not, I updated my xcode today.

Answer (score 0):

delete package-lock.json:
`sudo rm package-lock.json`

delete node_modules:
`sudo rm -rf node_modules`

optionally upgrade npm:
`sudo npm install -g npm`

and install project again
`npm i`

run project:
`npm start`

worked for me in the situation like you described