# sh: react-scripts: command not found

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, yarnpkg, oh-my-zsh

I'm taking a course on Udemy where we are going to use `create-react-app`. But when I come to run `npm start` and/or `yarn start`, I get an error.

This is the course: [Complete React Developer in 2020 (w: Redux, Hooks, GraphQL)](https://www.udemy.com/course/complete-react-developer-zero-to-mastery/)

npx create-react-app test-npm (and --use-npm if i'm using npm)

We suggest that you begin by typing:

cd test
 npm start

Happy hacking!
➜  Complete React Developer in 2020 (w: Redux, Hooks, GraphQL) cd test
➜  test-npm git:(master) npm or yarn start

> ```
> test-npm@0.1.0 start /Users/user/Udemy/Complete React Developer in 2020 (w: Redux, Hooks, GraphQL)/test
> react-scripts start
> ```

Result with npm:

> ```
> sh: react-scripts: command not found  
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE  
> npm ERR! syscall spawn  
> npm ERR! file sh  
> npm ERR! errno ENOENT  
> npm ERR! test@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`  
> npm ERR! spawn ENOENT     
> npm ERR!  
> npm ERR! Failed at the test-npm@0.1.0 start script.  
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:  
> npm ERR!     /Users/user/.npm/_logs/2020-01-23T18_09_30_919Z-debug.log
> ```

Result with yarn:

> ```
> ➜  test-yarn git:(master) yarn start  
> yarn run v1.21.1  
> $ react-scripts start  
> /bin/sh: react-scripts: command not found  
> error Command failed with exit code 127.  
> info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
> ```

I'm on mac (newest iOS), and using zsh with oh my zsh.

**My .zshrc file:**

```
(#) If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.  
(#) export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH

(#)Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.  
export ZSH="/Users/mhagen/.oh-my-zsh"

ZSH_THEME="robbyrussell"

plugins=(git nvm)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

export PATH="$HOME/.yarn/bin:$HOME/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin:$PATH"
```

**My .bash_profile file:**

```sh
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

I have installed:

```
➜  ~ nvm --version
0.35.2
➜  ~ node -v
v13.7.0
➜  ~ npm -v
6.13.6
➜  ~ yarn -v
1.21.1
```

I have tried to delete `node_modules` and package-lock/yarn lock files and installed them with both npm and yarn (deleted the project and new file every time).

I have tried to install create-react-app globally. But none of the tips I've found are working.

Hoping someone here can see what my problem is :/

Comment: what's your node version? Try to add `export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH` on the top of .zshrc

Comment: export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH did not work :/

Sorry for the pictures, it's my first question here. Thank you for the comments, hope this is better :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the solution that worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59235436/10225590
You can't have space in the name of any folder in the path to your project.

E.g. 
user/project 1/react `// This cause the error`.
user/project1/react `// This is okay`.

Comment: You're a lifesaver. I can't believe I wasted so much time on this 

Comment: I've had the same issue and spent hours trying to resolve that!