# How to run app after moving it from Ubuntu to Windows 7?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, linux, windows

I finished my app and I have to bring it for company to show them what it is and how it works. I dont need any hosting service since there is(in company) their own network. So I thought I might just copy the whole app on my pendrive, just like that. Obviously I got plenty errors so I decided to compress it and then move. It worked, I have my app moved from Ubuntu to my pendrive and for tests, I moved it out to my Windows. There problems start to begin.. I did install nodejs, obviously unpack the folder, did write " npm install " twice( once at the server-side to download the node_modules from there and once at the client-side) and I still keep getting the error :
[image]

About my app: Its a MERN stack with Redux, some bootstrap. There is obviously lots of node_modules like nodemon, concurrently, etc,etc..

Thanks for any try to help <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have't installed nodemon globally on the new OS.

Try:

```
npm install -g nodemon
```

And see if that works

Edit: You are now getting the error "react-scripts is not recognized as an internal or external command..." yada yada... You could install react-scripts, although it should be installed already.

```
npm install react-scripts
```

Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40546231/sh-react-scripts-command-not-found-after-running-npm-start) and try the suggested solutions:

Comment: It lets me connect my database and run my server but I still cant connect if I type "localhost:3000" in Chrome. CMD says that it doesnt recognize the 'react-scripts'

Comment: Please update your question with all new information

Comment: @Goteii Hmm you are now getting a different error and unfortunately I don't know the solution. I found this question that refers to a similar problem: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40546231/sh-react-scripts-command-not-found-after-running-npm-start

Comment: I did use "npm i react-scripts" and it worked! I get problems with compilation though but I will just ask about it in next question