# Npm start problem while installing react, and how to fix it?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, reactjs, npm, npm-install

After installing node and global create-react-app using 'npm install -g create-react-app' I start creating my first app using 'npx(or npm i tried both) create-react-app appname' and it was successfully created until I start the 'npm start' in 'appname' directory which gave me the following errors.

E:\Sang\React\myapp>npm start

> myapp@0.1.0 start E:\Sang\React\myapp
> react-scripts-start

'react-scripts-start' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! myapp@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts-start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the myapp@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Sang Tonsing\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-09-03T12_06_34_133Z-debug.log

This is my script code inside package.json

```
{
"name": "myfirstreact",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
"@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
"react": "^16.13.1",
"react-dom": "^16.13.1",
"react-scripts": "3.4.3"
},
"scripts": {
"start": "react-scripts start",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"test": "react-scripts test",
"eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
"eslintConfig": {
"extends": "react-app"
},
"browserslist": {
"production": [
  ">0.2%",
  "not dead",
  "not op_mini all"
],
"development": [
  "last 1 chrome version",
  "last 1 firefox version",
  "last 1 safari version"
]
}
}
```

Kindly please help me solve my problem, I am planning to build my own website using react. Thank You so Much

Comment: Please post text, not images of text.

Comment: @DaveNewton, okay i have updated the text too.... Please check it

Answer (score 0):

```js
"scripts":{
"start":"react-scripts-start",
"build":"react-scripts-build",
"test":"react-scripts-test",
"eject":"react-scripts-eject",
}
```

you have to go to your package.json file and look inside scripts,
you should see there start script. if you dont have just add it.

Comment: That line of code is actually there except the last '-' was missing in each line of code so in added the '-' in all the lines and there's still error but fewer errors so your code helps but there's still some more problems. The error is -- npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE, npm ERR! errno 1 and so on. Theres also an errror which says "This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely addiditonal logging output above". Hope it helps to find out the problem

Comment: I updated the screenshots of the errors kindly please check it.

Answer (score 0):

In your package.json file change the start script as:

> ```
> "scripts": {
>    "start": "react-scripts start -o",
>    "build": "react-scripts build",
>    .
>    .
>    .
> ```

I think it's `"start": "react-scripts-start"` which is causing problem for you.

Comment: Ok. Can you add the scripts section of package.json to your question?

Comment: Please take a look at this thread https://stackoverflow.com/q/40546231/7344164

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing the react-scripts module.
Run `npm install react-scripts --save` in your project and your package.json should be the way it was initially:

```
"scripts":{
"start":"react-scripts start",
"build":"react-scripts build",
"test":"react-scripts test",
"eject":"react-scripts eject",
}
```

Comment: i already have that script but still i tried but still not the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
nvm install 10.23.0
npm start
npm run build
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Can you please explain why these commands solve the OP's problem?

Answer (score 0):

Brother I think your npm version or nodejs version is outdated
You’ll need to have Nodejs >= **14.0.0** and npm >= **5.6** on your machine. Or use windows 8.1 , 10 . Not the windows 7

Answer (score 0):

Simple delete the node_modules folder and run npm install in the appname directory. Let me know if it don't help.

Answer (score 0):

1. delete **node_modules**
2. run **npm install**
3. after that run **npm start**

**if above does't work**

1. delete **node_modules**
2. delete **package-lock.json**
3. run **npm install**
4. and then **npm start**

**if above solutions does not fixed your problem, try the following this worked for me:**

if you want to start on another port or PORT command not found error then do the following steps:

1. open **package.json** file
2. inside **script** replace the **start** command with below **"start": "set PORT=3006 && react-scripts start"**

Comment: Grammar and formatting needs to be improved. You can also mark commands with backticks.