# When build express-react app, it shows error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I currently working in a react - expressjs project which was worked by someone before.
Currently, when I'm trying to run the command

> npm run build

The project shows me the following error:

[image]

What can I do with that error?

As an additional information (I don't know if that is related), when I try to deploy any change I do in the project it doesn't take it into account due as I understand, the deploy depends on chunk.js files (created by the build). I mean, chunk.js files are not been updated.
And in the configuretion of the deploy... the project specifies that I needs to point those chunk.js files

[image]

How can I change that configuration?

Here is my package.json file (the scripts section)

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please do not provide code and errors as screenshots, copy them to question. Also, provide minimal, verifiable example of your code.

Answer (score 0):

can you share your package.json Scripts ? there is a possibility you are missing the "build" Script

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

try to reinstall the dependencies again globally, check this link =>  reactgo.com/react-scripts-command-not-found and [sh: react-scripts: command not found after running npm start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40546231/sh-react-scripts-command-not-found-after-running-npm-start)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that. Added, thanks

Comment: try to reinstall the dependencies again globally, check this link => https://reactgo.com/react-scripts-command-not-found/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40546231/sh-react-scripts-command-not-found-after-running-npm-start