# Get sh: 1: react-scripts: not-found

Tags: reactjs, react-native, github, terminal

I'm trying to run this code from github: https://github.com/qccoders/startup-idea-generator

And I'm getting this error:

```
npm start

> startup-idea-generator-web@0.1.0 start /home/zaesar/startup-idea-generator/startup- 
idea-generator
> react-scripts start

sh: 1: react-scripts: not found

npm ERR! Linux 4.15.0-171-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v8.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! startup-idea-generator-web@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the startup-idea-generator-web@0.1.0 start script 'react-scripts start'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the startup-idea-generator-web package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     react-scripts start
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs startup-idea-generator-web
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls startup-idea-generator-web
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/zaesar/startup-idea-generator/startup-idea-generator/npm-debug.log
```

Followed the steps of [sh: react-scripts: command not found after running npm start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40546231/sh-react-scripts-command-not-found-after-running-npm-start) but with no success.

I'm newbie and any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure you are in the correct directory. I got the same error and resolved it by changing my directory (`cd project/directory`)

Comment: Yes I'm on the correct folder

Comment: @Zaesar first npm install and then do npm start.

Comment: I've done that `rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json && npm install && npm start `.No success

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Solve it by following:

Step-1: $ npm install

Step-2: $ npm start.

Thats all.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the node_module
Delete package-lock.json.
then "npm install"

Comment: I get `node_module: not found`. Thanks for answering

Comment: I've done like so rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json && npm install && npm start
`  but still with no success