# sh: 1: react-scripts: not found (After running npm start or yarn start i am getting this error)

Tags: reactjs

```
npm start

> demo@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

sh: 1: react-scripts: not found
```

After running npm start command my react project is not running and giving this error

i am using ubuntu 20.04

- node version 16^
- npm version 8^

Comment: before asking your questions, please check if a similar question was asked before. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40546231/sh-react-scripts-command-not-found-after-running-npm-start) you will probably find your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run `npm install` first

Comment: I changed  "start": "react-scripts start"
to 
"start": "NODE_ENV=production node_modules/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js start"
now it working for npm or yarn start but for build it is still giving this error what is the reason behind this ?

Comment: For it looks like fi you have package-lock.json missing or something like this

Comment: i am thinking it may be because of not successfully having link to react-scripts so do i have to change every script like this ?

Comment: I never have to do something like this. In my opinion reverting this script back to just react-scripts and removing node-modules and running `npm install ` should fix everything. If not that means you have an issue with npm configuration