# Command Not Found - npm run start - package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

In my package.json file, I have the following scripts:

```js
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

When I use "npm run" it shows the following available scripts:

```js
Lifecycle scripts included in swap@0.1.0:
  start
    react-scripts start
  test
    react-scripts test

available via `npm run-script`:
  build
    react-scripts build
  eject
    react-scripts eject
```

However, whenever I use "npm run start" or "npm run-script start", I get the following error: **sh: react-scripts: command not found**

Any ideas are appreciated; I can't seem to find any clues.

Comment: Can you show us where react-scripts is defined?

Comment: Those scripts are provided by the `react-scripts` package. If you have created your own package with "create-react-app" it should have installed it. If you have `react-scripts` in your `package.json` dependencies, maybe you just have to do `npm install`.

Comment: It is already answered here <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40546231/sh-react-scripts-command-not-found-after-running-npm-start>

Answer (score 0):

im pretty new to this too, but you're supposed to run "npm start" to run your application. remove the "run" part and try it out

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).