# Can't start TypeScript ReactApp. Error: react-scripts command not found

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I created ReactApp based on TypeScript, but when I try to start a server I'm getting an error.

```
$ npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript
$ cd my-app
$ npm start
$ sh: react-scripts command not found
```

Could someone help me figure out why this is happening? When I create ReactApp on JavaScript I don't have this error

Comment: Do you have `node_modules` folder?

Comment: Navigate to the folder that has your package.json and run `npm install` first.

Comment: found similar post 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40546231/sh-react-scripts-command-not-found-after-running-npm-start

Nothing from first 10 answers work in my case. BUT one work:  

In package.json change
```"start": "react-scripts start"```
to 
```"start": "NODE_ENV=production node_modules/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js start"```

Comment: did you installed `create-react-app` globally via `npm install -g create-react-app`?

Comment: no, the app was installed locally

Answer (score 1):

I think you have created a new project and are trying to start it.

To add TypeScript to an existing Create React App project, first install it:

```
npm install --save typescript @types/node @types/react @types/react-dom @types/jest
```

or

```
yarn add typescript @types/node @types/react @types/react-dom @types/jest
```