# npx create-react-app dependencies not working

Tags: javascript, npm, polyfills, npx, react-scripts

When creating a new react app via `npx create-react-app client`, the application is created however the react-scripts command is not found and cannot run the start script. Is there anyway to fix this? [[image]

Question 2 Also when running application `node <direct path to react-scripts start file>` I cannot use the dotenv module as pollyfill is no longer supported for the fs and os modules? Any solutions?

I am using

- npm version: 8.19.2
- node version: v16.17.0
  [image]

Comment: Why would you run the start file manually (Q2)? Can you show the error output for Q1 along with the command you're using?

Comment: Without react-scripts to run the file itself through the package you would have to run it manually to get it to run. This is how I have still been building with react this last week. 

```npx create-react-app client```
```cd client```
```npm run start```

Comment: Can you make sure you don't have react-scripts or CRA installed globally (npm uninstall -g ...) and then show the output when creating the app?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40546231/4722345

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this problem's have multiple problems , maybe you have to create app at desktop or at C disk (if Windows) , try this

1. rm -rf node_modules
2. rm -rf package-lock.json
3. npm install
4. change node version vie NVM (optional)

Second question check this [dotenv-webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack)

Comment: Error message same as i did before with your commands. Do you have a Node version that would be best for this workaround?

Comment: you can create react app where ever you want, you just have to provide public path

Comment: This solution did not work yesterday but fixes the problem today... I don't know what I did different to not work yesterday but thank you for the help!!